# Parse log with mixed single-line and multi-line content

Tags: regex

I need to extract messages from a log file. Messages are logged in two different ways: in a single line, like this:

```
2018-09-21 10:03:54,145 <message-content>
2018-09-21 10:05:02,008 <next-message-content>
```

or in several lines like this:

```
2018-09-21 10:03:54,145 <message-content-part 1>
<message-content-part 2>
...
<message-content-part n>
2018-09-21 10:04:12,198 <next-message-content>
```

Each message starts with header `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}`.
There is no any specific ending tag in each message.

I want to extract all messages, both single- and multi-line, with specific text.

For example, the output of search for "XYZ" could be like this:

```
2018-09-21 10:03:54,145 AAA BBB XYZ CCC
2018-09-21 10:10:55,347 BBB 
CCC XYZW 
DDD
2018-09-21 10:12:56,060 EEE XYZFFF
GGG
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/p6I4dq/1

Comment: [Another approach](https://regex101.com/r/p6I4dq/2).

Comment: Thank you, it works fine even on large files. But I am unable to use this pattern in grep command. Could you please help me?

Comment: You might try `grep -Poz '<PATTERN_ABOVE>'`

Comment: I tried this: $ grep -Poz "(?m)^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}(?:(?-h\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})[\s\S])*?TMOf7729857-ccaa-46b3-bdde-e1579484b4cc[\s\S]*?(?=^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}|\z)" server.log

grep: unrecognized character after (? or (?-

Comment: I have used pattern from your last approach: grep -Poz "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}(?:(?!^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3})[\s\S])*?TMOf7729857[\s\S]*?(?=^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}|\z)" server.log, but got "unrecognized character after (? or (?-"

Comment: There must be a better approach than this, try `awk`.

Comment: Try `cat file | sed -E 's/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}/\n\n&/' | awk 'BEGIN { RS = "\n\n"; ORS=""} /XYZ/ {print}'`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/10yIjH).

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Thank you, it works great, I tried it on large 50 Mb log files, it worked without any noticeable delay. Thank you for help!

Comment: I will post for you to accept / upvote then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
cat file | \
  sed -E 's/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}/\n\n&/' | \
  awk 'BEGIN { RS = "\n\n"; ORS=""} /XYZ/ {print}'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/10yIjH)

**Details**

- `sed -E 's/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}/\n\n&/'` - This sed command finds lines starting with datetime format and prepends them with double newline
- `awk 'BEGIN { RS = "\n\n"; ORS=""} /XYZ/ {print}'` - This awk command reads the file in splitting the file into records by "\n\n" (`RS` is the record separator), and only prints (omitting the `\n\n` because of `ORS=""`, where `ORS` is the output record separator) those that contain `XYZ` substring.

Answer (score -1):

Using perl. I added 2 more messages in the sample input, which should not appear in the output.

```
> cat pattern_xyz.dat
2018-09-21 10:03:54,145 AAA BBB XYZ CCC
2018-09-21 10:03:54,145 AAA BBB PPP CCC
2018-09-21 10:10:55,347 BBB
CCC XYZW
DDD
2018-09-21 10:12:56,060 EEE XYZFFF
GGG
2018-09-21 10:10:55,347 BBB
CCC QQQW
DDD
>
> cat pattern_xyz.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
$file=$ARGV[0];
$x=`cat $file`;

while($x=~m/(^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(.+?)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(.*)/osm)
{
$content="$1$2";
$x="$3$4";
if( $content=~/XYZ/  ) { print "$content"; }
}
> pattern_xyz.pl pattern_xyz.dat #executing script
2018-09-21 10:03:54,145 AAA BBB XYZ CCC
2018-09-21 10:10:55,347 BBB
CCC XYZW
DDD
2018-09-21 10:12:56,060 EEE XYZFFF
GGG
>
>
```