# Regex to extract last word, outside the brackets, in comma-delimited list of expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I guess, if it is possible to use regex to extract the last word of each expression in comma-delimited list, the word should be outside of nested brackets.

For example, for expression:

```
a(bb, ccc(dddd), ee, f(gg, h(i))) jjj, kk(ll) mm, n(o, p()) qq, r
```

the expected result is:

```
jjj mm qq r
```

I will use this regex in Python 3.

Comment: Posting your requirements and expecting someone to come up with tailor-made code [worked last time for you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52440197/2564301), but generally we appreciate a bit more effort on your own side. What have you tried, and how did it not work?

Comment: It seems a quite none-standard task for regex, so I need an idea. Unfortunatelly I don't have any, sorry.

Comment: This is not something that regexp is good for. It can't easily match inside/outside brackets.

Comment: Thank you, I think so too. I just wanted to check if there is some original solution that I don’t guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to look ahead and check that there is not only a comma following (or the end of the input) but also that what follows only consists of paired parentheses. 
For that latter check you would need recursive capabilities in the regex parser, which `re` does not offer. The [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) library supports it:

```
import regex

s = "a(bb, ccc(dddd), ee, f(gg, h(i))) jjj, kk(ll) mm, n(o, p()) qq, r"

res = regex.findall(r"(\w+)(?=,[^()]*(\((?>(?:[^()]|(?2))*)\)[^()]*)*$|$)", s)

# Keep only the matches of the first capture group
res,_ = zip(*res)

print(res)  # ('jjj', 'mm', 'qq', 'r')
```

The recursive part is the second capture group. It first starts with capturing a `(`, and then uses the `(?>` group to denote the base case, i.e. a series of non parentheses and the recursive case, i.e. `|(?2)`. The second capture group ends with capturing the paired `)`.

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.